# Accessibility testing (with Microsoft Narrator as screenreader)? Somebody here with some practical guidelines?

Tags: testing, accessibility, screen-readers, wcag

This is not a code question but more of a user testing question that I am hoping to clarify (also for sake of other (front-end) developers that are trying to be better at accessibility testing.

As a Windows user with wife that uses a MAC I try to use NVDA and Microsoft Narrator and then go to MAC and use it's voice over. Always feeling not quite 100% if my tests are good enough...

I have very limited screen-reader abilities and after reading a lot on them I found this useful page;
https://webaim.org/articles/screenreader_testing/ - especially this sentence here;

> Screen reader users are one of the primary beneficiaries of your
>   accessibility efforts, so it makes sense to understand their needs. Of
>   course, you don't want to fall into the trap of thinking that
>   accessibility is only relevant to screen reader users.

So - now to the question: how do you and your company cope with screen-reader testing ?

Do you have the needed competence level or do you out-source this (I think this needs to be tested manually but maybe somebody uses some advanced automatic tests too)?

And I found this one on MS Narrator:

> Windows Narrator is not a real screen reader, it is a toy!

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/27756562/3365805) - but now we are in 2020 and I would like to think that MS Narrator should be "better" - what are your experiences here?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for SO, see the [help] for guidance.

Comment: chuck the same question up on https://ux.stackexchange.com/ as you wont get people trying to close it there and i will try and drop an answer over later for you bud.

Comment: Moved to https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/132918/accessibility-testing-with-microsoft-narrator-as-screenreader-somebody-here-w

Comment: Closing after migration to UX.

Comment: answered it for you on UX, any questions just ask.